# With pure JavaScript, hide an element based on swatch active class and data-swatch-option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend, shopify

I'm trying to show a file upload button only for one of the swatch options named 'Custom Logo' in the test product page [here](https://shop.packedwithpurpose.gifts/products/copy-add-a-custom-logo?variant=40215066116156).

My code below is incomplete because I find it difficult to read the value of the `data-swatch-option` attribute and to find if the `span` has a class named `swatch--active` that indicates that the swatch in question is selected.

```html
<span data-swatch-option="Custom Logo" data-swatch-index="6947439312956-0" data-booster-initd="true" class="swatch--active">Custom Logo</span>
```

```js
  // Show File Upload button only if Custom Logo variant is clicked/active.
  const el = document.querySelectorAll('span');
  window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(input));
      document.getElementById('hulkapps_option_list_6947439312956').style.display = 'none';
      for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        const current = el[i];
        el[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
          if(current.dataset.swatchOption == 'Custom Logo'){
            document.getElementById('hulkapps_option_list_6947439312956').style.display = 'block';
          }else{
            document.getElementById('hulkapps_option_list_6947439312956').style.display = 'none';
          }
        });
      }
    }, 2000);
  };
```

Comment: There's not enough relevant code in the question to diagnose the exact issue, however I can tell you that your JS syntax is incorrect and will be showing an error in the console, which is the first place you should be looking when debugging JS issues. The line should be changed to `$("#hulkapps_custom_options_6947439312956").show();`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. In the first place, I'm not very sure how to read value from the attributes. If you did visit the page linked in the post, you would see what exactly I'm trying to do.

Comment: To read the data attributes use `data()`, eg `$(this).data('swatch-option')`. Also, as per SO question guidelines, all relevant information and code should be in the question. People should not have to go offsite to understand the context of what you're asking

Comment: I'm getting ideas. Can you tell me how I can attach a click event to this element `<span data-swatch-option="Custom Logo" data-swatch-index="6947439312956-0" data-booster-initd="true" class="swatch--active">Custom Logo</span>`

Comment: If that class is added after the element is clicked, then you don't want to attach an event handler to that class. Attach it to a parent of it, eg. `$('#container span').on('click'', .....)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```js
const el =  document.querySelectorAll('.type')
const input = document.getElementsByClassName('uploader')

input[0].style.display = 'none'

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  const current = el[i]
    el[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if(current.dataset.swatchOption == 'Custom Logo'){
      input[0].style.display = 'block'
     }else{
      input[0].style.display = 'none'
     }
      
    });
};
```

```css
span{
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 10px;
}

input{
margin-top: 50px
}
```

```html
<div class="swatches__holder">
<span class="type" data-swatch-option="Custom Logo" data-swatch-index="6947439312956-0" data-booster-initd="true">Custom Logo</span>
<span class="type" data-swatch-option="Design 1" data-swatch-index="6947439312956-0" data-booster-initd="true" class="swatch--active">Design 1</span>
 <span class="type" data-swatch-option="Design 2" data-swatch-index="6947439312956-0" data-booster-initd="true">Design 2</span>
<span class="type" data-swatch-option="Design 3" data-swatch-index="6947439312956-0" data-booster-initd="true">Design 3</span>
<span class="type" data-swatch-option="Design 4" data-swatch-index="6947439312956-0" data-booster-initd="true">Design 4</span>
<span class="type" data-swatch-option="Design 5" data-swatch-index="6947439312956-0" data-booster-initd="true">Design 5</span>
<span class="type" data-swatch-option="Design 6" data-swatch-index="6947439312956-0" data-booster-initd="true">Design 6</span>
 </div>
 
 <div class="uploader"><input type="file"></div>
```

Comment: Bobi, since we decided not to use jQuery for performance reasons, I request you to convert your answer into a pure JavaScript solution.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I need to edit your code according to the HTML in the page.

Comment: @PramodGangadar code is almost done i copied html from your website , if you think this is correct answer to your problem you can accept this as answer

Comment: Hi Bobi, there is no way I can add class type in the HTML because it is added by Shopify platform. Can you use something else other than `.type` to get all elements?

Comment: I updated the code in my post with your code with my editions. It is still not working. Could you please have a final look at it and correct it?

Comment: It is working great now. One last thing is that I'm looking to optimize `document.querySelectorAll('span');` Use of span may bring all elements in the entire document. Is there a better way to do this?